# connect to local endpoint (laravel) from flutter with physical device

Tags: laravel, flutter

For some unknown reason I can't connect to local endpoint on physical device.

Code:

```
String url = 'http://localhost/eltriodigital/public/api/prueba';
String url2 = 'http://192.168.56.1/eltriodigital/public/api/prueba';
String url3 = 'https://ecleectic.com/api/prueba';

  Future<Response> prueba() async {
    Response response =
        await get(url, headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'});
    return response;
  }
```

Tests I have performed:

If I try to connect to a production endpoint(url3) it works.

If I try to connect to local endpoint(url,url2) but from emulator it works.

If I try to connect to local endpoint(url,url2) from flutter web if it works.

Can someone tell me why I can not connect from physical device in local endpoint(url,url2)? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check this question
[How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)
It may has the solution for your problem